# WPF ユーザーコントロールの検証ロジックにパラメータを渡したい

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

WPF(.NET4.5/C#)でユーザコントロールを作成しています。
テキストボックスを拡張したもので、入力値の検証も実装します。
この検証ロジックに、次のような形でパラメータを渡したいと考えています。

```
<local:UserControl1 Value="{Binding Foo}" TargetType="{x:Type local:AnyType}" />
```

`TargetType`プロパティに、検証ロジックをカスタマイズするクラスを指定できる仕組みです。
この仕組みを実装するにあたり、[このサイト](http://oita.oika.me/2014/12/21/binding-to-validation-rule/)の解説記事を参考にしました。
できあがったコードが次の通りです。

UserControl1.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication1.UserControl1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>
        <TextBox>
            <TextBox.Text>
                <Binding Path="Value"
                         UpdateSourceTrigger="LostFocus"
                         RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}"
                         NotifyOnValidationError="True"
                         >
                    <Binding.ValidationRules>
                        <local:HogeRule>
                            <local:HogeRule.TargetType>
                                <local:DependencyType Value="{Binding TargetType, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"/>
                            </local:HogeRule.TargetType>
                        </local:HogeRule>
                    </Binding.ValidationRules>
                </Binding>
            </TextBox.Text>
        </TextBox>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

コードビハインド

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    // Value 依存関係プロパティ
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Value",
        typeof(object),
        typeof(UserControl1),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(default(object), FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault));

    // Value CLRプロパティ
    public object Value
    {
        get { return this.GetValue(ValueProperty); }
        set { this.SetValue(ValueProperty, value); }
    }

    // TargetType 依存関係プロパティ
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TargetTypeProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "TargetType",
        typeof(Type),
        typeof(UserControl1),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(default(object), FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault));

    /// TargetType CLRプロパティ
    public Type TargetType
    {
        get { return (Type)this.GetValue(TargetTypeProperty); }
        set { this.SetValue(TargetTypeProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

基本となる検証ルール

```
public class HogeRule : ValidationRule
{
    public HogeRule()
    {
        this.TargetType = new DependencyType();
    }

    public DependencyType TargetType { get; set; }

    public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, System.Globalization.CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
        // TargetType.Valueを使って処理をカスタマイズ
    }
}
```

Type型をデータバインドで渡すために使うDependencyObject

```
public class DependencyType : DependencyObject
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Value",
        typeof(Type),
        typeof(DependencyType),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(default(object), FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault));

    public Type Value
    {
        get { return (Type)this.GetValue(ValueProperty); }
        set { this.SetValue(ValueProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

しかし、このコードを動かしても、`HogeRule.Validate`が実行された時点で、`TargetType.Value`は`null`になっています。
`UserControl1.xaml`の

```
<local:DependencyType Value="{Binding TargetType, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"/>
```

の行を

```
<local:DependencyType Value="{x:Type local:AnyType}"/>
```

と固定で書いた場合には正常に動作するので、ここのバインディングがうまくいっていないのだと思います。
しかし、どこか違っているのか分かりません。
ただ、やりたいことは、ユーザコントロールの利用者が検証用のパラメータを指定できるようにしたいだけなので、全く別のアプローチでも構いません。

Answer (score 1):

スコープに依存する`Binding.ElementName`ではおそらく無理です。[参照先の記事](http://oita.oika.me/2014/12/21/binding-to-validation-rule/)は`{StaticResource}`を利用しているためビジュアルツリーを無視してVMが解決できているのだと思います。

なので無理やり解決するのであれば`CollectionViewSource`のような特殊なクラスを用いて、例えば

```
<UserControl.Resources> 
    <CollectionViewSource
        x:Key="cvs">
        <CollectionViewSource.Source>
            <CompositeCollection>
                <local:DependencyType
                    Value="{Binding TargetType}" />
            </CompositeCollection>
        </CollectionViewSource.Source>
    </CollectionViewSource>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

とリソースを定義しておいて

```
<local:HogeRule.TargetType>
    <local:DependencyType
        Value="{Binding Source={StaticResource cvs}, Path=CurrentItem.Value}" />
</local:HogeRule.TargetType>
```

するなどの酷い方法を使う必要があります。

またビジュアルツリーを変更しても良いのであれば、

```
<UserControl>
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <Grid x:Key="grid" Visibility="Collapsed" />
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <StaticResourceExtension ResourceKey="grid" />
        …
    </Grid>
<UserControl>
```

のように隠しコントロールを配置しておいて`{Binding Source={StaticResource grid}, Path=DataContext.…}`と同インスタンスを使う方法もあります。

Answer (score 0):

検証はしていませんが、`UserControl`と`local:DependencyType`が親子関係になっていないように思います。
UserControlにx:Nameで名前を付け、DependencyType側はElementNameで参照してはどうでしょうか。

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication1.UserControl1"
         x:Name="UserControl"
         (省略)
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">

<local:DependencyType Value="{Binding TargetType, ElementName=UserControl}"/>
```